# How to apply linear layer to 2D layer only in one dimension (by row or by column) - partially connected layers

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm trying to apply a linear layer to a 2D matrix of tensors connecting it only by column as in the picture below.

[image: 1D linear layer applied to 2D layer]

The input shape is **(batch_size, 3, 50)**. I first tried with 2D convolution, adding a 1 channel dimension, so input shape is **(batch_size, 1, 3, 50)**

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class ColumnConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1,
                out_channels=1,
                kernel_size=(3, 1),
                stride=1,
            ),  # shape is B, 1, 1, 50
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten() #shape is B, 50
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I'm planning to use a list of 50 `nn.Linear` layers and apply them to column slices of input, but it seems much more like a workaround not optimized for performance.

Is there a more *"pytorchic"* way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyTorch [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear) module can be applied to multidimensional input, the linear will be applied to the last dimension so to apply by column the solution is to swap rows and columns.

```
linear_3_to_1 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

x = torch.randn(1, 1, 3, 50)
x = x.transpose(2, 3) #swap 3 and 50
out = linear_3_to_1(x).flatten()
```